# Calculating time taken to answer correct questions only

Tags: android, eclipse

Iam doing an IQ test app.I consider time taken by th test takers to determine IQ (in my way),but Iam encountering a problem.It is that if I just consider the time taken The IQ goes very high because it doesn't matter if you have selected the right or wrong answer.So,What Iam considering is time take to answer correct questions.I think from that way I can get an near view of IQ.can someone help?

This is AgeCalculation.java

```
package com.example.iqtest;
public class AgeCalculation extends Activity implements OnTouchListener
{


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_age_calculation);
    mDate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edDate);
    age = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edAge);
    calage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCalculateAge);
    go = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    category=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.category);
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    Year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    Month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    Day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    mDate.setOnTouchListener(this);


    calage.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
            Calendar now=  Calendar.getInstance();
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

            calendar.set(Year, Month, Day);

            int years = now.get(Calendar.YEAR) - calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            int months = now.get(Calendar.MONTH) - calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int days = now.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) - calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
            if (days < 0){
                months --;
                days +=now.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
            }
            if (months < 0){
                years --;
                months +=12;
            }
            String yearsold = years+" YEARS "+months+ " MONTHS "+days+" DAYS"+" "+"OLD";
            age.setText(yearsold);
            if(years>=0 && years<=10)
            {
                opt=0;
            }else if(years>=11 && years<=15)
            {
                opt=1;
            }else if(years>=16 && years<=30)
            {
                opt=2;
            }
            else if(years>=31 && years<=50)
            {
                opt=3;
            }else if(years>=51 && years<=120)
            {
                opt=4;
            }else
            {
                opt=5;
            }
            switch (opt) {
            case 0:
                start=0;
                end=21;
                indtime=10;
                temp=" KIDS";
                timetotake=480;
                break;
            case 1:
                start=21;
                end=38;
                indtime=11;
                temp=" CHILDREN";
                timetotake=480;
                break;
            case 2:
                start=38; 
                end=56;
                indtime=12;
                temp="TEENAGERS";
                timetotake=540;
                break;
            case 3:
                start=56;   
                end=76;
                indtime=11;
                temp="ADULTS";
                timetotake=540;
                break;
            case 4:
                start=76;  
                end=99;
                indtime=13;
                temp="ELDERS";
                timetotake=600;
                break;
            case 5:
                temp="ALIENS!!";
                break;
            default:
                temp="ALIENS!!";
                break;
            }
            category.setText(temp);
            go.setText("GO"+" "+"TO"+" "+temp+" "+"IQTEST");
            }
    });

    go = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttongo);
    go.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()        
    {
        public void onClick(View view)
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(AgeCalculation.this, QuizActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }


}); 
}

@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id)
{
    switch (id) {

        case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
            return new DatePickerDialog(
                this, DateSetListener, Year, Month, Day);
    }
    return null;
}

private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener DateSetListener =
    new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener()
    {

    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
            int dayOfMonth) {
        Year = year;
        Month = monthOfYear;
        Day = dayOfMonth;
        String sdate = lp(Day + "", "0", 2)+ " " + montharray[Month] + " " + Year;
        mDate.setText(sdate);

    }

};

 private  String lp(String sc, String sp, int len) {
        String sr = sc;
        for (int i = sr.length(); i < len; i++) {
            sr = sp + sr;
        }
        return new String(sr);
    } 
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {

    showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);
    return false;
}
}
```

This is QuizActivity.java

```
package com.example.iqtest;
public class QuizActivity extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_quiz);
    timerValue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    startTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
    customHandler.postDelayed(updateTimerThread, 0);
     pause = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pause);
     pause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View view) {
            timeSwapBuff += timeInMilliseconds;
             customHandler.removeCallbacks(updateTimerThread);
            pause.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
           Intent i = new Intent(QuizActivity.this,Timeplease.class);
           startActivity(i); 
         }
     });
    agecal = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttoncalage);
    agecal.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()        
    {
        public void onClick(View view) 
        {
            Intent i = new Intent(QuizActivity.this,AgeCalculation.class);
            startActivity(i); 
            finish();
        }

}); 
    DbHelper db=new DbHelper(this);
    quesList=db.getAllQuestions();
    currentQ=quesList.get(start);
    txtQuestion=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    rda=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio0);
    rdb=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio1);
    rdc=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio2);
    rdd=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio3);
    rde=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio4);
    butNext=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    setQuestionView();
    butNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {     
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            RadioGroup grp=(RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);
            RadioButton answer=(RadioButton)findViewById(grp.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
            if(currentQ.getanswer().equals(answer.getText()))
            {
                score++;
            }
            if(start<end){                  
                currentQ=quesList.get(start);
                setQuestionView();
            }else{
                Intent intent = new Intent(QuizActivity.this, ResultActivity.class);
                Bundle b = new Bundle();
                b.putInt("score", score);
                b.putInt("time",secs);
                //Your score
                intent.putExtras(b); //Put your score to your next Intent
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        }
    });
}
private void setQuestionView()
{
    txtQuestion.setText(currentQ.getquestion());
    rda.setText(currentQ.getopta());
    rdb.setText(currentQ.getoptb());
    rdc.setText(currentQ.getoptc());
    rdd.setText(currentQ.getoptd());
    rde.setText(currentQ.getopte());
    start++;
}
private Runnable updateTimerThread = new Runnable() {
public void run() {
timeInMilliseconds = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - startTime;
updatedTime = timeSwapBuff + timeInMilliseconds;
secs = (int) (updatedTime / 1000);
int mins = secs / 60;
secs = secs % 60;
int milliseconds = (int) (updatedTime % 1000);
timerValue.setText("" + mins + ":" + String.format("%02d", secs) + ":"+ String.format("%03d", milliseconds));customHandler.postDelayed(this, 0);
}
};
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
           startTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
customHandler.postDelayed(updateTimerThread, 0);
}
}
```

Comment: Would this still not make an IQ too high? If I answer everything as quickly as possible, and have about 50% right, will this not also skew the results?

Comment: What you might do is to take the time someone answered and then take the ratio of their correctness with it. If they take longer to finish the test but have more correct answers they will get the same points as someone who is fast but has a few wrong. By using this someone who is fast and correct will get the highest score.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say you should check how many questions are answered correctly in the specified time, check like that

Don't go by the time only

each and every time the user presses an answer to a question check whether he clicked the correct answer or not and keep a tag like within 1minute how many questions did he answered correctly, if he answers 5 questions correctly within a minute then IQ is high, if 1 then low, something like that

lets hope the test is of 15 minutes having 15 questions
create a timertask of 1 minute and copy the score into a vector or arraylist and set the score = 0 every time your timer task starts itself

Your timertask should end when the test is supposed to end,

when the test time is up check the size of the arraylist and add up the values in the arraylist

if the arrylist size is 15 and the correct question is also 15 then give it s % as you wish, so on

Comment: thats what I want to know how?Iam a new bee.Can you please show it in code?